# Next React - ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I have two reusable functions where I use `window.localStorage.getItem` method.

```
const userByToken = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const token = window.localStorage.getItem("token");
    const refreshToken = window.localStorage.getItem("refreshToken");
}
```

this function returns error for using `window`

but second function

```
    const useValidateToken = (setLoadingState: any) => {
      const router = useRouter();
      useEffect(() => {
          const token = window.localStorage.getItem("token");
          const refreshToken = window.localStorage.getItem("refreshToken");
      })
    }
```

doesn't return error.

why do I get error without `useEffect`?

Comment: In addition to the linked resolution - the *why* is most likely because server-side NextJS only performs the first render, so `useEffect`s are not called. But your first snippet is not in an effect, so it tries to call it during the server-side rendering

Answer (score 3):

Next pre-renders components firstly in the server, where the `window` object does not exist.

You have to use `useEffect` or add kind of guards to avoid crashing when running the first render

```js
  const isBrowser = !!window; // Feel free to define which is the best way to detect when is being runner in the browser
  if (isBrowser) {...}
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond, so it's not possible to use window without useEffect

Comment: You should use `typeof window !== 'undefined'` check. Calling `!!window` will raise ReferenceError on server-side.

Comment: You right @Aitwar, my demonstration was vague

Comment: Hi, this answer is wrong, you need the guard to be wrapped into an effect. See the other question in the duplicate notice.